# Laravel Eloquent Nested Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I currently have a nested relationship working fine in the following code

```
Tickets->with('A.B.C')

[{A:AB_Relationship:{BC_Relationship:{}}]
```

However I need it to work something similar to `Tickets->with('A.B.(C  or d)')`

```
[{A:AB_Relationship:{BC_Relationship:{},BD_Relationship:{}}]
```

How can I get the relationship from B.D to be included in as well?

Comment: something like: Tickets->with(['A.B.C','A.B.D'])

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array to `with` that accepts multiple nested relationships.  It should only run a single query for each of the parent relationships (one query for A, one for B, and one each for relationships C and D) so it shouldn't be doing any unnecessary duplicate queries fortunately.

```php
Tickets::with(['A.B.C', 'A.B.D']);
```